# Is there an R function for creating spatial weight matrix for “spatial difference in differences” method?

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, geographically-weighted-regression

I am trying to apply "spatial difference in differences" method in R for a US county's block groups (n block groups) over 2 different times (2000 and 2015).

In order to do this spatial regression over two years, I need to create a spatial weight matrix based on a contiguity list of neighbors.

Based on a paper by [Delgado(2015)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2637764), this spatial weight matrix is a

> (2n*2n) block-diagonal row-standardized spatial weights matrix containing non-zero elements for spatial units belonging to contiguity class.

Can anyone let me know of an R function for creating such a neighbors' weight matrix that can be created for a county block groups' shapefiles over two years and then used for spatial difference in differences specification?

Comment: pretty late on this so I'm guessing you figured out a solution, but do you need two separate spatial weight matrices? did the areas become differently aggregated, and if so, how are you analyzing them? The `spdep` package includes `poly2nb` and `nb2listw` which sound like they would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @cschwab98 for your reply. I found the 2 following packages for this spatial panel data model: 1. spml package in R, 2. Spatial panels package in MATLAB by Paul Elhorst.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards this Faizeh! I would be interested in reading your paper if you have it posted anywhere, I am doing a similar project but with multiple treatment groups and variations in treatment time using the `did` package, and also have been struggling to deal with the presence of spatial dependence in my dataset.

Comment: Sure, I will let you know when my paper is published. I found the Spatial Panels Matlab package very useful. You can use spatial models like spatial lag or spatial error to handle the spatial dependence in your data.

Comment: Fantastic, I'm very excited to read!